# Simple and short true-false tasks regarding Precalculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, education

Here are few of the questions from the previous years' exams. I've chosen the ones I'm not sure about. It's a simple TRUE/FALSE task. Would anyone be able to verify my solution? Some of my answers are good, some are just random guess according to my intuition. I don't really need a *detailed* explanation... Thanks!

1. Domain of $f'$ is contained within domain of $f$. - TRUE
2. Boundary point of set A is also a cluster point of that set. - TRUE
3. Every increasing sequence and bounded above is convergent. - TRUE
4. Every increasing sequence and bounded below is convergent. - FALSE
5. Every increasing sequence is always bounded below. - TRUE
6. Every sequence is discontinuous function. - FALSE
7. Every sequence is continuous function. - TRUE
8. Every function integrable on $<a, b>$ is continuous on $<a, b>$. - FALSE
9. Function $f(x) = \ln{|x|}$ is discontinuous at $0$. - TRUE
10. The continuity is necessary for differentiability. - TRUE
11. Function $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is monotonic. - FALSE

Comment: I would say you missed 2, 9, 11

Comment: How come the $11$ is wrong? Isn't a *monotonic* function such a function that increases on all of its domain? Also, what about 9th question? $\ln(x)$ is not defined at 0 so it's discontinuous at $0$ I assume?

Comment: I do not know what is "cluster point" (language problem). For the rest: 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10 are fine for me. 9  - for me is the function not defined at 0, so it cannot have a property there. 11 - f is monotonic!

Comment: For 11: Constant functions are monotonic. Monotonicity is usually distinguished from *strict* monotonicity. For 9: it is neither continuous nor discontinuous at a point that is not in its domain; it is simply undefined there.

Comment: Monotonic signifies "doesn´t change from increasing to decreasing and vice versa".

Comment: @user376343 : Not quite, since constant functions can be regarded as increasing or decreasing anywhere you like (you would need to be more specific). A function $f:X\to Y$ is *monotone* if $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected (or empty) for each $y\in Y$. In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are (subsets of) $\mathbb R$, this means $f^{-1}(y)$ is a (possibly degenerate) interval for each $y$ in the image. We confirm this by noting that the image is $\{-1,1\}$ and the preimages are $f^{-1}(-1)=(-\infty,0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)=(0,\infty)$ which are both connected.

Comment: What about this? **Question:** function $f(x) = \ln{|x|}$ is continuous. False or true? I say it's false because it's not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: If a function is not defined at a point, it is irrelevant to ask whether she is or is not "something" at that point. The function you are given is continuous at any point of its domain.

Comment: Thanks! (10 char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right
2. Wrong (What is the boundary of $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb R$? What is its set of cluster points?)
3. Right
4. Right
5. Right
6. Right
7. Right
8. Right
9. Wrong (it isn't defined there)
10. Right
11. Wrong (think about what this function *is*)

Comment: It's up to you.